# How to enable a drop down after disabling it?

Tags: javascript

I am facing a drop down disabling problem here . I have two conditions here, cond1 and cond2 .If its the cond1 i will disable my drop down menu, else i will enable it.

This is what i fished out :

```
if(cond1)
{
DP1.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
else
{
DP1.setAttribute('disabled', false);
}
```

The problem is once the drop down gets disabled , its not getting enabled again . For eg if its cond2 , then it must be enabled . What am i doing wrong ? Kindly suggest some solution to this.

Comment: Thanks guys , i dunno how i missed that. Thanks again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `removeAttribute` would do the trick: `DP1.removeAttribute('disabled');`

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/qXsNu/), using that

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `disabled` attribute

```
DP1.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Alternatively, you can set the element's boolean `.disabled` property directly ([more details](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/deform3.shtml)):

```
DP1.disabled = !cond1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the attribute `disabled` with `removeAttribute`

```
   if(cond1)
    {
    DP1.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else
    {
    elem.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/uqenez/1/edit